# how to apply dcc interval on the selected drop down value

Tags: python, plotly, dashboard, plotly-dash

I would like user to first select an patient id from the drop down menu, that selected id will then be refreshed using `dcc.Interval` to obtain his current blood pressure live in text output (real time via database).

However, I can only obtain the blood pressure of a patient but still have to refresh it by f5 for new reading pressure.
How do I modify my second callback and its relevant function?

I tried lookup those tutorials but still not sure how to mash things up. Thanks.

My **app.layout**:

```
app.layout = html.Div([

                html.Div([dcc.Dropdown(id='dropdown',
                                    options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in x],
                                    value='x',
                                    clearable=False),
                        html.Div(id='table-container')]),

                html.Div([html.Div(id='live-update-text'),
                          dcc.Interval(id='interval-component', interval=2000, n_intervals=0)])

])
```

**Respective callback**:

```
#First callback and its function [working as expected]
@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('dropdown', 'options'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('dropdown', 'value')])
def get_update_db_dropdown(value):
    #connect to database and then return the results.

#Second callback and its pseudo function; I want this to be self refresh/live updating via dcc interval process
@app.callback(
    Output('live-update-text', 'children'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('dropdown', 'value')])
def set_display_livedata(value):
    #connect to database and obtain blood pressure where id=value
    return f'selected {id} has {bloodPressure}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To trigger the callback periodically, you must add the `Interval` component as an input. Hence, your second callback should be

```
@app.callback(
    Output('live-update-text', 'children'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('dropdown', 'value'), dash.dependencies.Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals')])
def set_display_livedata(value, n_intervals):
    #connect to database and obtain blood pressure where id=value
    return f'selected {id} has {bloodPressure}'
```